# Mongoose save function not saving entire document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When I go to use `.save()` on a Mongoose Schema object, the object does not entirely get saved to the database - only certain parts of the JSON do.  Further, the return from the `.save()` does not match what is in the database.

```
export const updateSWAMRequest = async (req, res) => { // remember, cannot add fields that aren't in model.
    const incomingData = req.body;

        console.log("-------------------------------------")
        console.log('incomingData from user :>> ', incomingData);
        //  { 
        //    Reevaulate: { A: 'alphie'} 
        //  }
        console.log("-------------------------------------")

    MyDataSchema.findOne({ _id: req.params.requestID }, (error, dataObj) => {
        console.log("-------------------------------------")
        console.log('dataObj from DB :>> ', dataObj);
        //  { 
        //     Household: { reviewStatus: 'Approved' },
        //     Reevaluate: { A: 'bonnie' }
        //  }
        console.log("-------------------------------------")
        
        Object.keys(incomingData).forEach(key => {
            dataObj[key] = incomingData[key]
        })

        dataObj['Reevaluate'].test = "111"
        dataObj['Household'].test = "111"

        console.log("-------------------------------------")
        console.log('dataObj after Mods :>> ', dataObj);
        //  { 
        //     Household: { reviewStatus: 'Approved', test : 111 },
        //     Reevaluate: { A: 'alphie', test: 111 }
        //  }
        console.log("-------------------------------------")

        dataObj.save()
            .then((returnObj) => {
               console.log("-------------------------------------")
               console.log('returnObj :>> ', returnObj);
               //  { 
               //     Household: { reviewStatus: 'Approved', test : 111 },
               //     Reevaluate: { A: 'alphie', test: 111 }
               //  }
              console.log("-------------------------------------")
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    id: dataObj._id,
                    message: 'Data updated!!',
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(409).json({
                    success: false,
                    error,
                    message: 'Request found, but not updated!',
                })
            })
    })
}
```

This is all basically exactly as I would expect -- the incoming data has been merged with the existing data that came from the database and the selectively changed 'test' items have been returned from the Mongoose `.save()` function.

**The problem is**: that the database value after all of this running is:

```
     { 
         Household: { reviewStatus: 'Approved'},
         Reevaluate: { A: 'bonnie', test: 111 }
     }
```

Only the top-level key that was sent with the `incomingData` object ends up making it to the database.  Any attempts to modify the `dataObj.Household` object don't go through.

I'm a bit at a loss -- as I though the whole point of `save()` was to take that object and save it to the DB and then return the new DB value.   ... it does not appear to be doing this.   I don't know where to look.

MyDataSchema is very simple:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const MyDataSchema = new Schema(
    {
        "_id": String,
        "Reevaluate": {},
        "Household": {},

    }, { timestamps: true }
)
export default mongoose.model('requests', MyDataSchema)  ///'requests' is the collection in the database
```

EDIT: further looking shows that if I replace `dataObj['Household'].test = "111"` with `dataObj['Household'] = {...dataObj['Household'], test : "111"}` then everything seems to work fine AND it gets saved to the DB.  I wonder if there is some higher-level key reference that isn't getting updated when the object contents are updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor and simplify your code like this:

```
export const updateSWAMRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let data_object = await MyDataSchema.find({ _id: req.params.requestID })
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => { data_object[key] = req.body[key] })
    data_object.Reevaluate.test = "111";
    data_object.Household.test = "111";
    await data_object.save();
    return res.status(200).json({success: true, id: dataObj._id, message: 'Data updated!!' 
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(409).json({success: false, message: 'Request found, but not updated!', error})
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  The reason I don't use FindAndUpdate is because in the actual code I need to look at some of the values that come out of the DB in order to set other values.  (ie: I look at a bunch of 'reviewStatus' values and come to a 'finalStatus' conclusion).   Can I do this within the findByIDAndUpdate?

Comment: Then I guess that the best way is to just fetch the document first, calculate the `finalStatus` conclusion, and then modify the whole document at once.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (honestly - I'm new to Mongo) -- am I not doing that in the original question?

Comment: Yes you did, but you didn't calculate any new data from the actual document from the database (at least not in your example). You just fetched the document, modify its fields, and then save it. All of that you can do with `findByIdAndUpdate` in one query.

Comment: Nice.  okay, thank you!  Even though nothing came of this, I much appreciate the input.  Any thoughts why the save doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: I update answer with `console.log()` before and after the update. Can you add it also and add the response in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231899/discussion-between-lowcrawler-and-nenad-milosavljevic).